# I am getting loss=nan while training the FC layer of resnet with pretrained weights in keras

Tags: python, keras

Here is the code 
I'm loading the pre-trained model

```
img_width, img_height = 299, 299
model=applications.resnet50.ResNet50(input_shape=(img_width, img_height,3),weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

Freezing all layers of resnet

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

stacking FC layers

```
x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(20, activation='softmax')(x)
model_final = Model(input = model.input, output = predictions)
```

Now I'm compiling and fitting random test samples

```
model_final.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
s=np.random.rand(10,20)
s1=np.divide(s.T,np.sum(s,axis=1)).T
model_final.fit(np.random.rand(10,299,299,3),s1, nb_epoch = 30, callbacks=[], validation_data=None)
```

During training phase I'm getting Nan as the loss

> Epoch 1/30
>
> 10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan - acc: 0.1000

even while train with actual dataset also, its giving 'nan'

I couldn't find nan at each layers output.

I'm unable figure out was might be causing this error.